# Create table with squares and cubes and colors, how to produce the desired effect?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, export, color, syntax

This should be very simple but I do not get as I want,
I have tried, with print, grid, matrix but it doesn't work.

Is for my niece, is to create a table of squares and cubes with big bold letters size 14, where the table of squares is painted blue but legible and the cubes painted only up to 15 green and from there down red (the idea is to be as striking as possible and that the complete table can be printed on a sheet of oficio size in pdf (216mm x 330mm, with a title centered, which says table of squares and cubes), help me with the syntax, please.

I've been looking at examples on this site, but I can't find any suitable ones.

[image]

edit

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thegrid = 
 Column[{Text[
    Style["Table of Squares and Cubes", 
     FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS", FontSize -> 14, 
     FontWeight -> Bold]], 
   Grid[Prepend[
     Table[{Style[n, Black], Style[n^2, Blue], 
       Style[n^3, If[n <= 15, Green, Red]]}, {n, 1, 50}], {n, n^2, 
      n^3}], Frame -> {All, {1}}, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontWeight -> Bold, 
      FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"}]}, Alignment -> Center]
```

Call `Rasterize` on this to get an image you can print out or export to PDF:

```
Export["grid.pdf", thegrid]
```

[image]

Comment: @flinty_hi thank you, it is exactly what I am looking for, how can I make the pdf look like the attached image and not so thin? and with the numbers below moderately proportional to those of the headers
 see editing

Comment: @zeros add more spacing in the `Grid` by adding `, Spacings -> {4, 0}]` in the `Grid` options

Comment: @flinty_, hi it works thank you, but how would you put lines for each row, as in the example

Comment: @zeros your first example doesn't have lines. You could just remove `Frame -> {All, {1}}` to put the lines back.

Comment: @flinty_yes, sorry I was in the first drawing to put the lines, do what I indicated and everything disappears, I have looked for different combinations but do not come out, also how to make the dividing lines are not as thick as those of the header